# stuck on NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults

bit of a noob here. I haven't been able to solve my problem by reading these boards - can anyone spot a problem with this:

I have a label, which I would like to update daily, I've attempted this using NSUserDefaults.

```
    -(id)init{
    ...
    ...
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    NSString *todaysDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", date];

    [self createLabel:todaysDate];
    }

    -(void)createLabel:(NSString*)theDate{

     if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:theDate] == nil){

     myLabel.text = [someOtherClass getAppropriateString];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[mylabel text] forKey:theDate];

}else{

    myLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:theDate]

  }

 }
```

EDIT:

Thanks for your help guys. While writing this question, I actually realised my mistake!

Just did a quick test.

If anyone's interested: the string from today's date included minutes and seconds, meaning each time I ran the app and saved it as NSUserDefault, it would be different.

I added a date formatter and it now works.

Comment: forgot [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to `synchronize` your changes. Add a `[[NSUserDefaults] synchronize];` line after the `setObject:forKey:` line

Comment: I am just going to say what i learnt about using synchronize. NSUserDefaults has intelligence mechanism to write things  persistently. So do not call synchronize unless it is for debugging. Here he should probably use instance variable. Using local variable with userDefaults is inefficient.

Comment: synchronise - From the Apple docs:"Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes."

Comment: Sometimes you can't wait for the automatic synchronization and you have to manually do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
-(void)createLabel:(NSString*)theDate
{
     if([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:theDate] == nil){
         myLabel.text = [someOtherClass getAppropriateString];

         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[mylabel text] 
                                                   forKey:theDate];
         [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
     }else{
         myLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:theDate];
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterStyleLong];
NSString *todaysDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
```